# SQL Query outputting wrong

Tags: sql, select, join, sql-order-by

I'm trying to make a SQL Query, that outputs every category in my categories table. Aswell as counting every thread connected to category. Now, that works fine, but when I try to add a new field, where I need to show the latest thread datetime, it goes wrong.

This is my SQL so far:

```
SELECT categories.category_name, 
       categories.category_id, 
       COUNT(threads.thread_category_id) AS 'threadCount', 
       threads.thread_datetime
FROM   categories LEFT OUTER JOIN 
       threads ON categories.category_id = threads.thread_category_id
GROUP BY categories.category_name, categories.category_id, threads.thread_datetime
ORDER BY threads.thread_datetime DESC
```

*This is resulting the following:*

[image]

But what I actually want it to output is this, and also a field besides it with the thread_datetime of the latest thread in my threads table, based on ORDER BY

[image]

I've been trying different JOINS, aswell as many other resources. Can't seem to find a way that works.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Probably MySQL judging by the incorrect usage of `GROUP BY`: http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (having moved the datetime from your group by to an aggregated part of the select)

```
SELECT categories.category_name, categories.category_id, 
COUNT(threads.thread_category_id) AS 'threadCount', MAX(threads.thread_datetime)
FROM categories LEFT OUTER JOIN threads ON categories.category_id =     threads.thread_category_id
GROUP BY categories.category_name, categories.category_id
ORDER BY max(threads.thread_datetime) DESC
```

Comment: That seemed to do the trick. Never thought of using MIN & MAX before. I'll accept your answer, when I can. Thank you!

Comment: @KevinJensenPetersen, does the trick, except it gives a different schema to the one specified in the question and unordered data.

Comment: @KevinJensenPetersen, if this is the right answer its the same as JodyT's which seems to be 2 minutes earlier by my reckoning. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15475227/659190

Comment: @Jodrell Good point with the sorting, I've edited to reflect. I don't understand what you mean about the schema, as I copied the OPs code and edited that solely by moving the thread_datetime to the SELECT clause

Comment: I mean the OP doesn't include the `DateTime` column in the result set on the second grid but its presumably still used for ordering.

Comment: Ah, then I disagree with you. ;-) the OP writes that he wants what is in the second grid "...and also a field besides it with the thread_datetime"

Comment: MIN and MAX works as ORDER BY. Also, since I saw this answer by Anders UP First on my question. I'll accept that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MAX()` to get the latest date for each group.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT 
    categories.category_name, 
    categories.category_id, 
    COUNT(threads.thread_category_id) AS 'threadCount', 
    MAX(threads.thread_datetime)
FROM categories 
LEFT OUTER JOIN threads 
    ON categories.category_id = threads.thread_category_id
GROUP BY categories.category_name, categories.category_id
```

Answer (score 1):

something like,

```
SELECT
                categories.category_name, 
                categories.category_id, 
                COUNT(threads.thread_category_id) AS 'threadCount'
    FROM 
                categories
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                threads 
                    ON categories.category_id = threads.thread_category_id
    GROUP BY 
                categories.category_name,
                categories.category_id
    ORDER BY 
                max(threads.thread_datetime) DESC
```